# How to recover my reputation and account after accidentally deleting my email address

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-recovery

I have accidentally removed my email address from my profile. When I have tried to recover it, my points and badges were automatically reset. Is there a way to recover my reputation and badges?

Comment: If you happen to remember your previous user ID (your current ID on Stack Overflow is 1397766) then email the team with both and ask for a merge.

Comment: How exactly did you remove the email? Can you explain what you did step by step?

Comment: If you can't remember your previous user ID, you can still use @ShaDowWizArd's [suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all#comment367432_132689) by searching for a question or answer you had posted, and getting your previous user ID from there.

Answer (score 3):

> I have accidentally removed my email address from my profile. when i have tried to recover it my points and badges are automatically reset.

That email address is used for delivering newsletters and fetch your gravatar; it isn't used to tie your account.

My guess is you tried to log in with a different email which resulted in a new account being created for you. Try to recall one of your questions/answers, and then flag for moderator attention to have the accounts merged.

Comment: Don't flag, since mods don't have the ability to merge accounts anymore. You'll have to [contact staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have created another account by using new credentials (email id/open id). So, if you try to log in with the previous credentials/OpenID, you will get to see your points/badges earned by you.

Comment: ITs the same email id i m using now... all the points are reset...